# Diagrama de BD tipo de relaciones

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Buenas tardes queria consultarles estuve realizado la relacion de estas tablas quería saber si es correcto y si quisiera agregar la entidad o banco al cual pertenece la tarjetas tendría que agregar una tabla mas y como quedaría la relacion ?.Desde ya muchas gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A priori la entidad o banco seria una tabla mas con una relación 1:N (un banco --> N tarjetas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desde el punto de vista comercial, es decir el mundo real, una tarjeta puede ser emitida por un banco, o por una entidad madre (AmEx, Visa, MasterCard). En cualquiera de esos casos, se requiere una tabla para poner esas entidades y la relación por FK en la tabla Tarjeta.
En resumen, si, necesitas la tabla ENTIDAD_EMISION (por ejemplo), y la relación en TARJETAS.

Posdata: El estandar especifica que los nombres de las tablas van en singular, no plural. En la universidad me hubiesen reprobado si ponía plural.